# Tranform.Rotate css text for print window not working web page

Tags: html, css

I want to print my data in 90 degree that is rotated CSS style not working.

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 2):

it always works, show me your code. See this example:

```css
.mydata{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#4caf50;
  color:#f3f3f3;
  padding:5px;
  
  /* rotate here */
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<br>
<div class='mydata'>
mydata
</div>
```

you use `transform:rotate(90deg)` inorder to rotate your text!